# How to implement a new design from scratch in magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, design

I want to create a custom design by my self in magento 2.1 (without simple data version), how can I create it , with any resources please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is extremely broad, Magento frontend theme development is a complex subject covering a wide range of development skills that cannot simply be answered here.

Start by reading the official [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html) and work with the supplied Magento 2 themes.

Learn now to extend and customise the default themes and decide if you can use these to meet your requirements. Depending on how you want to customise your theme you might also consider a commercially available theme that you can purchase and then further extend and customise.